# Can Guard be used programmatically without a Guardfile?

Tags: guard

I would like to use Guard inside of custom rake tasks for different needs. Instead of loading the Guardfile to configure the gem, equivalent configuration would be defined within the tasks themselves.

I would prefer not to depend on a Guardfile. However, the Guardfile itself appears to be a requirement for the gem to work. I have not found a workaround in the Wiki or in various articles demonstrating Guard trickery.

Is this possible using existing parts of the Guard gem, or would it need to be extended in order programmatically configure it?

Answer (score 0):

There's an up-to-date wiki entry on this here:

https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Use-Guard-programmatically-cookbook

If something doesn't work, just file an issue here: https://github.com/guard/guard/issues/new